# How do I set whether a form redirects to a new page or not?

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to create a simple log in page with `php` and `html`. It's pretty simple. First, a user inputs their username and their password, then clicks the submit button.

If the username/password combo is invalid, "Invalid log in." is printed, and the user is redirected back to the log in page.
If the username/password combo is valid, "Logging you in..." is printed, and the user is redirected to another page. **All POST data must be kept when redirecting**.

I can't figure out how to change the form's action.

Code snippet below. Please look past potential SQL injections. I will deal with them later.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="form">

User Name:<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">

<?php
$username = $_POST['userName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//(omitted) function that checks whether the credentials are valid or not
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo "Logging you in...";
    //TODO: function that redirects user to another page
}
else {
    echo "Invalid log in.";
}
?>
```

Comment: in the if condition save the credentials in the session, then use the header function to redirect to someplace else like homepage

Comment: In addition to @kevinabelita you'll need to arange your code so nothing is output before the `header()` call

Comment: actually you really dont need an `action` attribute since your processing it in the same page, and yes, no output before the header function

Comment: @kevinabelita Actually, `action` required by the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3). It may work without it, but shouldn't be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the header function and choose where to redirect.
Per other's suggestion, nothing should be echoed before calling header. We can check if the current request is a POST or a GET. For POST, we can do authentication, and for GET, we output the form. We can use the `$_SESSION` variable to check if we are redirected from a successful or failed login attempt.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userName'])) {
    $username = $_POST['userName'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        $_SESSION['login_success'] = true;
        header('Location: user.php?login_success=1');    
    } else {
        $_SESSION['login_success'] = false;
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['login_success']) && !$_SESSION['login_success']) {
    echo "Invalid log in.";
    unset($_SESSION['login_success']);
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="form">

User Name:<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
```

In user.php, we can check the `$_SESSION` variable as well.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login_success']) && $_SESSION['login_success']) {
    echo "Successful login.";
    unset($_SESSION['login_success'])
}
```

Comment: This will not work given the current page setup. No output can come before `header`... I think you have the right idea, but the code will need to be rearranged for this to work.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are on the login page. Thus no need to replace the code after `} else {`.

Comment: Good answer. It works completely for me, however, I would still like to keep the echo of logging in or invalid log in. Is this still possible?

Comment: @user2837858, It is possible if we start a session. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to first show the text and then redirect. Your flow is as follows:

1. user enters credentials,
2. user gets confirmation of process,
3. user gets logged in

This way, the server will handle 3 requests (send credential form screen, send confirmation of process screen, send logged in/index). I don't see why you would need to show he is logging in. From a UX perspective, the user will know he is logging in (he filled in the form and pressed the button) and it could break his experience as the screen may flash content, confirming log-ins is non-standard. Also, people don't like waiting. So you could skip that and use [User3678068's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101827/1388285).

If you really want to use this flow. You could use a Javascript redirect on the second page, with a timeout function (so users actually see the confirmation), while maintaining serverside state using $_SESSION or another cookie solution.

UX-wise, this is not an ideal solution because of aforementioned reasons and because it is harmful to visitors that have Javascript turned off.

Alternatively, you could send a Javascript notice on the credential form page, telling the user he's logging in. People without Javascript won't see the notice but get logged in anyways.

Comment: I can forgo telling users that they are logging in, however, telling them that their log in credentials are incorrect is a "should have", no?

Comment: It is indeed desirable to get some feedback. This is not a confirmation of process, but a response to the process. So, after seeing the credentials are invalid, you would send back the same form with a little pop-up/notice informing the user the credentials aren't correct (or something like that). 

Also, you might want to implement some sort of serverside thresholding system, slowing down response times if the client regularly sends invalid credentials.